# Apply one function on every fields which will get from database table : cakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, html-entities

I want to apply one function called `htmlentities` in every field which retrieve from table.

how can i do this? i have used `beforeMarshal` but its only affect while save data in database. its not affecting while retrieve data from database.

So is there any function in cakaPHP that i can make the functionality possible as above I don't want to write this function each and every place that i am retrieving I want global solution that i will change at one place and it will affect to every fetch data?

I want to apply `htmlentities` because to not affecting code from user like content `<script>alert("u have hacked");</script>`

Comment: You may use call back functions like afterFind..!

Comment: @Manohar Khadka  Where should i write `afterFind` function? in model or controller? i have tried it to set in model and controller too but its not working

Comment: Have a look here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html

Comment: You can also use h() function in your view 

https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/function-h.html

Comment: @Gransfall, `h()` is for `htmlspecialchars()` but i want to use `htmlentities()` and my concern is to make this global so i dont need to write this everywhere.